# web.py Json with Multiple select

Tags: jquery, python, html, json

I am using Web.py framework.I have a dynamic dropdown in my html page which is working fine using jquery and json.But when I add the select tag with a multiple attribute I receive a key error in web.py.How can I avoid this problem.

**EDIT** :I get the following error in python
 **s = web.input()['text']
 KeyError: 'text'**

P.S:I am a novice in web development

This is my json/jquery Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#primaryl").bind('change click', function() {
        var pid = $$(this).val();
        if (pid != '') {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "PUT",
                url: "/getloc",
                async: false,
                data: {text: pid},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(regions) {
                    $$("#secl").empty();
                    $$("#secl").append("<option value='0'>SECONDARY</option>");
                    $$.each(regions, function(index, region) { $$("#secl").append("<option>" + region + "</option>"); });
                }
            });
        } else {
            jQuery("#secl").html("Failed");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<!--first select-->
<select name="primaryl" id="primaryl" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="0">PRIMARY</option>
</select>
<!--second select-->
<select name="secl" id="secl"><option value="0">SECONDARY</option></select>
```

web.py code:

```
class Getloc:
    def PUT(self):
        s = web.input()['text']
        result = db.select('location')
        for user in result:
            if user.lname == s:
                lid = user.lid
        result = db.select('location')
        sec_dict = []
        i = 0
        for users in (result):
            if users.lparent==lid:
                sec_dict.append(users.lname.encode('ascii','ignore'))
                i = i + 1;
        if i == 0:
            sec_dict = ['None']
        return json.dumps(sec_dict)
```

Comment: Please post your error traceback.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\******", line 170, in PUT
    s = web.input()['text']
KeyError: 'text'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it really looks like the problem is on the JavaScript/AJAX side. the web.py code just always does the same thing and doesn't seem to have anything at all that could potentially be causing any bugs.

Your best bet is to inspect the outgoing HTTP request with Firebug or the built in development/debug console of Chrome or Safari, to see if the `text` parameter is really present in both cases.

Also, here's a more sane version of your Python code with comments:

```
import json

import db
import web


class Getloc(object):
    def PUT(self):
        s = web.input()['text']
        # doesn't the DB layer web.py allow you to directly query the rows
        # that match your criteria? filtering in your code is inefficient
        for user in db.select('location'):
            if user.lname == s:
                lid = user.lid
                break  # once found, save CPU time and don't keep iterating

        # sec_dict = []  # this is not a dict, it's a list, but it's not
                         # needed anyway--use list comprehensions instead

        # i = 0  # not needed in this case, but if you need iteration with
                 # indexing, use `for ix, elem in enumerate(elems)`

        # same question--can't you just have the DB do the filtering?
        ret = [user.lname.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
               for user in db.select('location')
               if user.lparent == lid]

        # if not ret:
        #     ret = [None]  # this is a bad idea; just return an empty list

        return json.dumps(ret)
```

Comment: Although I didn't get the solution to the real problem .Just found out how bad I am in python/web.py :) .Thank you so much for your remark btw.

Comment: using a normal select:text:abcd and With multiple select : **text[ ]:abcd**.So how to pass array in jquery/json to back end.

Comment: So I would just try `input = web.input(); s = input.get('text', input['text[]'])` then.

Comment: Thank you so much !! Its working pretty well !! I dont have enough reputation to give you an upvote it seems !! Anyway thanks a lot again :)

Comment: Accept will do just fine :P (actually I didn't know it was not possible to upvote like this)

Comment: I am new to SO.Need atleast 15 reputation to upvote.and this being my first question in SO.It will take some time I think to get to 15.